# Chardin.js absolutely positioned z-index issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a basic tour to this project using Chardin.js: 
[Click green marker here](http://www.artandseek.net/xchange/)
But I can't seem to get the button to rise above the overlay.

I already found [this](https://github.com/heelhook/chardin.js/issues/26) via Google, but it provides no real answer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case this helps anyone else out....I was setting the parent z-index by adding a class to make it the active layer, but this was forcing the button below the overlay.  So in instances where the overlay is shown, I now make the parent div z-index:auto which allows the button back on top of the overlay.

Answer (score -2):

Solution:

```
.stay-visible 
{
  z-index: 9999999;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: relative;
}
```